# Estimating probability density function of big amount of data coming from Monte Carlo simulation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, matlab, optimal-control, monte-carlo

I am trying to estimate Probability Density Function (PDF) of a big amount of data ($1e^6$ , $1e^7$, and higher) coming from Mote Carlo (MC) simulation.

My objective is to estimate the PDF (e.g. with Kernel Density estimation), and then extract the maximum point of this function that shall correspond to the mode of the population.

I am getting quite stuck in calculating this PDF (both with MATLAB using *ksdensity* function, and with R through fMultivar package and *desnity2d* function), because of the size of the population. Both MATLAB and R return error in allocating vectors of many GBs, and I suppose this is not the right way. I am saving the output population in .csv file.

To put you more in context.

The output of each MC iteration, namely $\bar{y}$, is the solution of an Optimal Control Problem where a **2D**(bivariate) normal distrbution stochastic variable is inserted, i.e. $\bar{x}$. Therefore, the PDF of $\bar{x}$ is $\mathcal{N}\sim(\mathbf{\mu,\Sigma})$ (where $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ are the vector of expected value and diagonal covariance matrix of $\bar{x}$, respectively) and $\bar{y}$ is also a bidimensional variable with unknown distribution in principle . So my doubt is:

Once I run a MC simulation using numerous samples of $\bar{x}$ extracted from bivariate normal PDF, how can I calculate the PDF of $\bar{y}$ ?

I hope my question was clear,
many thanks you in advance for your useful support.

Comment: Maybe you could make a histogram from your data (so count how often data points appear in a certain intervals). In this case you do not have to have all your data loaded at the same time.